# rudux with react-native dont work -- (0, _combineReducers.default) is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, jsx

i made exactly same like in react app, but in react is working, in react-native doesnt work

app.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './redux/reducers/combineReducers'

var Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
export default function App() {
  return (<Provider store={store()}>  // if i write store={store} error: undefined is not an object (evaulating 'store.getStare')
      </Provider>
  );
}
```

combinedReducers.js

```
import { key} from "./reducerKey";

    import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
    
    export var reducers = combineReducers({
        storeKey: key,
    })
```

reducerKey file

```
export var key = (state = 0, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'changeKey') {
        return action.playload
    }
    else {
        return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are trying to destruct {store} which doesn't exist in combinedReducers.js

Comment: You are exporting "reducers" and importing "store". Should it not be this, `import { reducers } from './redux/reducers/combineReducers'`. Also, I think you should do something like this, 

`import { reducers } from './redux/reducers/combineReducers';
const store = reducers();
<Provider store = { store }>
 <App />
  </Provider>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't create the `store` instead you are trying to export the `reducer`.

In the `combinedReducers.js`:

```
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   storeKey: key,
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer)

export {store}
```

Now in the `App.js`, you can use the `store` (without calling it):

```
import {store} from 'path/to/store';

// rest of the codes ...
<Provider store={store}>
// rest of the codes ...
```